# Conic Sections and Foci of Ellipses

Tags: conic-sections

We're just learning about ellipses and conics, and I'm a bit confused with ellipses, parabolas, circles, and hyperbolas, so a little help with this sample problem would be great.

In which of the following equations would the ellipse have foci on the y-axis, the x-axis, or neither?

$1=\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{16}$

[image: Graph for the first equation]

$1=\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}$

[image: Graph for the second equation]

I tried graphing these already, but I'm still not exactly sure where the foci lies. 
In fact, what does each number in the equation of an ellipse represent? I apologize for the very ignorant questions, but we just started learning about conics. :)

Comment: One may speak of where a focus lies, or of where the two foci lie, but not of "where the foci lies".  "Foci" is the _plural_ of "focus". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I apologize for the misuse of words. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the exact location of the foci in order to know what line they are on.  They are always on the major axis.

Comment: So would the two foci lie on the y-axis?

Comment: In the first case above they're on the $y$-axis; in the second on the $x$-axis. ${}\qquad{}$